# How to dynamically deny access using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am familiar with denying access based on an IP, block of IPs, browser, URL etc... but my problem here is, let me state, how to deny access if it came from some IP address, at least 3 times a second for long period of time. Here, you don't know the IP address unless you look at the access file. By the time you found out the IP address it's already drawn too much of the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use htaccess for doing this. The out-of-box apache directives can't handle browsing sessions. You'll need to install some sort of log parser, maybe something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)? Or you can probably cook up a set of iptables rules for blocking lots of connections from one IP: https://askubuntu.com/questions/437059/linux-command-to-prevent-dos-attack-by-using-netstat-and-iptables